# php, Echo mysql query by ID

Tags: php, mysql, variables, echo

I'm trying to display items for a database on my index, but only from the id's I want, not the whole table. So far ive tried this but it does not work:

Download.php

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

$con=mysqli_connect("kennyist.com","user","pass","table");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `wp_wpfb_files` WHERE `file_id`=" . $id);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And im trying to echo it like this (saw something like this before):

```
<div class="version"><?php echo('download.php?id=27', $row['file_version']);?></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) is now under [deprecated mysqli functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysqli.php)! this means, its better to go for the object oriented version instead!

Here's an example of how you do that :

```
$link = new mysqli ("kennyist.com","user","pass","table");

/* 
if id is a string then go for this version 

$id = $link->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
*/

$id = intval($_GET['id']); // if id is integer, this is better 

if ( $link->errno )
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: {$link->error}";
}

$result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM `wp_wpfb_files` WHERE `file_id` = $id");

if ( $result->num_rows ) $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$link->close();
```

Even better would be to use prepared statements, but if you're not familiar to them it could get a little tricky at the very beginning! Anyway, now you can do as the thing as requested!

```
<div class="version">
    <?php echo "download.php?id=27{$row['file_version']}"; ?>
</div>
```

The thing you're trying to echo out still needs a few things to be true, in order to prevent errors to occur :

- `file_version` must be a column within your table
- `$_GET['id']` must be set in order to set the proper `$id`
- there must be a record in the table for the corresponding `file_id`

### Notice

```
echo "download.php?id=27{$row['file_version']}";
```

Will always print out the same `id` on any give page, what you probably want is to forward the right `file_id` to your download.php page! You do this with something like :

```
echo "download.php?id={$row['file_id']}&version={$row['file_version']}";
```

### Hint

> [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) fetches an array both indexed and associative by default, if you don't need the indexed one just go for [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead!
>
> > [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows for the resultset represented by the result parameter.
> >
> > [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/kennyi81/public_html/dev/index.php on line 159" with this

Comment: @Kennyist what does your line 159 look like?

Comment: Im using the notice part, but its only displaying "download.php?id=" --- http://dev.kennyist.com/index.php#down First part of Downloads --- This is returning the right stuff though in the download.php --- http://dev.kennyist.com/download.php?id=27

Comment: @Kennyist i did some edits to my post, try to refresh the page... well it should be displaying at least `download.php?id=&version=` in the worst case!

Comment: @Kennyist if the answer helped you, eventually consider leaving a vote or accepting ;)

Comment: Ah sorry, None of these got it to work really, but yours at least made the php show something.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT " . $id . "  FROM wp_wpfb_files
```

If id=27, your query will look like

```
SELECT 27 FROM wp_wpfb_files
```

I think you need query like:

```
SELECT id, file_version FROM wp_wpfb_files WHERE id = $id
```

Comment: I've updated the top for what i wanted but i get this on the index.php:       Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/kennyi81/public_html/dev/index.php on line 157   --- That line is the echo line show above

Comment: `echo 'download...'` - remove the bracket which is right after the echo, end which is closing it

Comment: Do you have file_version column?

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: nvm my answer, op edited his question to change his query like in my answer

try modifying your $result assignment like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT file_version FROM wp_wpfb_files WHERE id = ".$id);
```

Edit: Removed code which assumes id is a string

Comment: Why do you assume ID to be a string?

Comment: yes it is wrong to assume it is a string since if it was, op would have quotes when he was concatenating the id.